# Full calendar custom view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there tutorial about full calendar custom view creation? I need to create view based on basic week view. Unfortunatelly, theres no documentation about it and I failed to find basic week view definition (only found abstract class baseView).

EDIT: Well, looks like it's not an easy question, so I have one simpler, is there a way how to change month view to use only one row with all days in it?

Answer (score 1):

The statement about missing documentation is wrong. Look [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/) and find a detailed description as well as links to examples

Comment: Well, from my point of view, this is not an example of documented custom view infrastructure ...

Comment: And, that's the best, the only "documentation" is not up to date because internals are not "standardised" and change over time.